# Unity OnMouseDown detect which button via Event Trigger

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is there any way to detect which mouse button that was clicked on a UI element carrying the Event System UI component?

I have objects in my scene with a script containing OnMouseDown. When clicking on the GameObject I can check if the left or right button was clicked:

```
public void OnMouseDown()
{
    if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))  print("clicked left button");
}
```

However, these objects also have a Text element on a canvas and I'd like the MouseDown to also fire when the text is clicked. I've attached an Event Trigger that points to the MouseDown. In this case `print("clicked left button")` is never reached. I'm guessing it must take a frame to pass the event data or something?

I can attach a separate script to all the Text elements and use the EventSystems interface (`OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)`) but if possible I'd like to avoid extra scripts. So, my question is: is there any way to pass the button that was clicked using the [Event System component](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-EventTrigger.html)?

Things I've tried:

1) Using `Input.GetMouseButtonDown` in MouseDown instead of `Input.GetMouseButton(0)`

2) Including `PointerEventData` as a parameter in MouseDown (results in an error)

3) Using the EventSystem API:

```
public void Clicked(PointerEventData p)
{
    if (p.button == PointerEventData.InputButton.Left)
    {
        print("UI Click");
    }
}
```

But this void doesn't appear in the available functions list on the Event Trigger component.

Comment: Your #3 should work Is there a problem with it?

Answer (score -1):

pointer events are using raycast targets. text element is not raycast target by it self (not clickable). if you want to trigger click events on texts, you can add image which is covering your text. dont forget set raycast target checked and make sure its layer is not something that ignores raycasts. you can also set your text child of a panel which also has image as raycast target by default.

in short: you can use pointer events only on gui elements/game objects which are raycast targets.